# Remove webform field while edit webform submission

Tags: 7

I have one [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and need to do that there are 2 fields, TL approval and Manager approval, now if manager submission page will edit by admin then TL approval field should not be load, in short i want to remove specific fields role wise when webform submission will edit. If anyone have an idea about this then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download & Install [Webform Fields Permission](https://www.drupal.org/node/1054650) module.

**Note :** Please read comments if you have any query.

If your issue not solved then try once [Webform Component Roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_component_roles) module.

Comment: Hello NishantP,
I have already used this but i have given all permission to admin user so that both fields are shown there. So i have to do this by another way to don't load that field by role permission.

Comment: Yes, issue is not solved through this. let me explain you again, admin has all permissions still if admin will edit submission which has filled by managers then TL approval should not be load in manager's edited submission.

Comment: Have you created roles for TL & Manager ?

Comment: Yes created for both separately

Comment: Have you tried both the modules. I think mainly issue from permission part, try to concentrate permission tab for both the roles.

Comment: Yes i have tried but still let me concentrate with all permissions. I will let you know after checking all permissions

Comment: Ok. Concentrate on permission for both the roles & also check configuration setting for this module.